# SqlPackage.exe - Export Azure Db to blob storage

Tags: powershell, azure, export, blob, sqlpackage

Can you use sqlpackage.exe to trigger an export database to BLOB storage?

Surprisingly enough I cannot find any reference to doing this.  The parameters for "sqlpackage /a:export" do not have any parameters that specify blob storage, just File|Memory.

Right now we are using Powershell AzureRm components, where we have to make a request and then loop for the status.  This works for the export fine, but find that the status check request is flaky, therefore it breaks the script's overall progress periodically.

The sqlpackage.exe call would be a blocking call which would eliminate the need for the additional error handling logic.

Thanks for any insight